# PHP save a resized image

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, image-resizing

I have this PHP script that resizes an image and displays the resulted image:

```
$filename = 'my-image.jpeg';

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_width = 1200;
$new_height = ceil($height * ($new_width/$width));

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
```

Now I want to save the image instead of displaying it, keep the original, and name the newly created image as "my-image-resized.jpeg", how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [`imagejpeg` function reference](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php), function definition is:

```
bool imagejpeg ( resource $image [, mixed $to [, int $quality ]] )
```

second parameter (e.g. `$to`), is described as below:

> The path or an open stream resource (which is automatically being closed after this function returns) to save the file to. If not set or NULL, the raw image stream will be outputted directly.

Because you've passed `NULL` to the `$to` param, it is streaming directly, which means displaying. In order to save it to file system, you should do sth like this:

```
imagejpeg($image_p, 'sampleImage.jpg' , 100);
```